# Where can I set system workflow messages (if I can)?

Tags: system-workflow-messages

I've translated and modified some Workflow messages like shown in the attachment especially Membership - Receipt and since then the new members don't get this message. I can set back to default but I would rather keep the translations and modifications.
I guess that if I can modify them (text and content) then this shouldn't perturbate the system but then I should be able, when it's not automatically done, to set some parameter somewhere 'when a membership' is pending then send 'Adhésion - reçu' message.

The question is where? I can't find.

Should I do this with CiviRules or set the message's name back to english?
Any help?

[image]

Comment: Apparently, the title of the message (not the subject of the email within the message) has to stay in English. I set everything back to default and changed again the name back to the exact words and now it works again.

Comment: Yes I think that's a limitation here. As you've noted the recipient doesn't see that though, just staff. But it would be a useful improvement to allow changing. The msg_template table doesn't currently have a spot for a display "label".